# Counting frequencies in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, frequency

I have a dictionary with a bunch of lists, ie:

```
{"0": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], "1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], etc...}
```

How can I count the frequencies of the numbers in each list? and output a dictionary in the format:

```
{"0": {"0": 4, "1": 2}, "1": {"0": 12, "1": 4}, etc..}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this for *one* list?

Answer (score 1):

use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

spam = {"0": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], "1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
eggs = {key:Counter(value) for key, value in spam.items()}
print(eggs)
```

output:

```
{'0': Counter({0: 4, 1: 2}), '1': Counter({0: 12, 1: 4})}
```

of course you can convert `Counter` to `dict` if you prefer

Comment: may or may not matter, but the op's expected results have the keys as strings and not ints

Comment: @python_learner - good observation. They can transform the `Counter` object further as they wish. But strictly speaking e.g. `'0'` is not present in the value for key `'0'`

Comment: yeah that was what I was thinking as well and hence the may not matter part :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a counter yourself, that just counts for every element in the list how many appearances it has (notice that you can use an integer as a dictionary key and not just a string). Like this:

```
a = {"0": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], "1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
different_a = dict()
for key in a.keys():
  counting_dict = dict()
  for e in a[key]:
    if str(e) in counting_dict:
      counting_dict[str(e)] += 1
    else:
      counting_dict[str(e)] = 1
  different_a[key] = counting_dict
```

But let's look at an nicer way than just counting the number of elements.

My favorite is to use collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
new_a = {key: Counter(value) for key, value in a.items()}
```

It turns the list into a set (a sort of list where each element can only appear once and the order of elements has no meaning), with the added feature that it counts the number of appearances. Read more about this data structure [here](https://realpython.com/python-data-structures/#sets-and-multisets).

Comment: better to use `a.items()` in your dict comp like the other answer suggests

Answer (score 0):

Try this (d is your dict):

```
d={"0": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], "1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

res={i:{'0':k.count(0), '1':k.count(1)} for i,k in d.items()}

>>>print(res)

{'0': {'0': 4, '1': 2}, '1': {'0': 12, '1': 4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```py
d = {"0": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], "1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],}

a = dict()

for k,v in d.items():
    count = dict()
    for x in set(v):
        count[str(x)] = v.count(x)
    a[k] = count
    
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'0': 4, '1': 2}, '1': {'0': 12, '1': 4}}
```

Or You can do it using Dictionary Comprehension:

```py
d = {"0": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], "1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],}

a = {k:{str(x):v.count(x) for x in set(v)} for k,v in d.items()}

print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'0': 4, '1': 2}, '1': {'0': 12, '1': 4}}
```